# enabling 'EventStore' in ServiceFabric fails

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to enable EventStore in ServiceFabric, but the upgrade fails.

`fabric:/System/EventStoreService` fails to start.

**Desired Behavior:** enable EventStore

[image]

**Specific Error Message:**

```
02/14/2019,11:18:04.325442 AM,1026,Error,.NET Runtime,,,Application: EventStore.Service.Setup.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
   at EventStore.Service.Setup.Program+PortAclUtility.BindCertificate(System.String, Int32, Byte[])
   at EventStore.Service.Setup.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

([diagnostic logs](https://gist.github.com/fnbk/0b4e99a8ecd04cbf8282c0d44ed75019#file-arm-template-json) on the node)

**DETAILS**

- Service Fabric Version: 6.4.637.9590
- [ARM Template](https://gist.github.com/fnbk/0b4e99a8ecd04cbf8282c0d44ed75019#file-arm-template-json)
- [diagnostic data](https://gist.github.com/fnbk/0b4e99a8ecd04cbf8282c0d44ed75019#file-diagnostics-data-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the cluster certificate is stored in `Root` certificate store on the VMs by accident - which actually works - `EventStore/BindCertificate` cannot access it. Place the cluster certificate in `My` certificate store.